# Random number macro does not return desired value

Tags: vba

I have created a simple module that is meant to do following:

- generate random number between 0 and 999;
- if number is lower than 500, assign value "lower", otherwise "higher"
- write the random number and assigned value in cells A1 and B1
- repeat the process 100,000 times.

Problem is, it returns assigned value "lower" even if the number is higher than or equal to 500, i.e., all assigned values, 100,000 of them, are "lower"!

I'd appreciate if someone can check where I'm going wrong with this code; I'm not an expert in VBA, but I thought I could do this myself... :\

```
Sub MacroRanNum()

   Dim RunNum As Integer
   Dim Outcome As String

For i = 1 To 100000

   Randomize
   RanNum = Int((999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)

   If RunNum < 500 Then
   Outcome = "Lower"
   ElseIf RunNum >= 500 Then
   Outcome = "Higher"
   Else
   Outcome = "Error!"
   End If

Sheets("podatak").Cells(i, 1) = RanNum
Sheets("podatak").Cells(i, 2) = Outcome

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If I were you I would call Randomize just once. Contrary to what one could believe this can make the numbers less random. (PS: this does not answer your question).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I will check, I read that Randomize should be called each time, so I put it within the loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing your variable names.  You define and check against RunNum but your random value and your display value are RanNum.  You are never testing against the value you randomly generated.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable name is

```
RanNum
```

but you check for

```
RunNum
```

[`OPTION EXPLICIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/y9341s4f.aspx) could help to avoid such problems.

Comment: Oh, damn, what a stupid mistake, lol... I was checking the code and thought something was wrong with the code, I didn't look at typos, phew... Thanks a lot!